# What's this error? I am trying to install create-react-app

Tags: reactjs

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
at Object. (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.19.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\socks-proxy-agent\dist\agent.js:114:44)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object.

Comment: node 10 is pretty old-ish. try updating to the latest node.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your node version then it will work fine..

Answer (score 0):

First, update npm,

```
npm install -g npm stable
```

Then update node,

`npm install -g node` or `npm install -g n`

check after version installation,

`node --version` or `node -v`